# Please don't bite

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> When things gets shaky, you can use me to keep it together,
>   but that might also get you one step closer to your demise.
>   When I get close to ten inches long, I make nice music,
>   but using me on a board is far from melodic.
>   Carpenters enjoy my company,
>   but one of them might disagree.
>   It is bad manners and a bad idea to bite,
>   someone who is as hard as me.
>   You might lose some teeth, which will add to my arsenal to fight you.

Who am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are a...

> Nail

*When things gets shaky, you can use me to keep it together,*

> Metal [nails (fasteners)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nail_(fastener)) are inserted into objects (usually wooden) to maintain a stable structure.

*but that might also get you one step closer to your demise.*

> The phrase "[another nail in the coffin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/another+nail+in+the+coffin)" means an event that continues a downward spiral to a bad outcome, such as toward death. (credit to [Peter Taylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52815/please-dont-bite/52816?noredirect=1#comment161965_52816))

*When I get close to 10 inches long, I make nice music,*

> Refers to the band [Nine Inch Nails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Inch_Nails).

*but using me on a board is far from melodic.*

> The sound of hammering a nail is considered loud and unpleasant. The sound of fingernails scraping a chalkboard is also horrible (credit to [Peter Taylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52815/please-dont-bite/52816?noredirect=1#comment161965_52816)).

*Carpenters enjoy my company, but one of them might disagree.*

> Carpenters use nails to build objects out of wood. The "one" who disagrees refers to Jesus Christ, who was a carpenter, and eventually nailed to a wooden cross.

*It is bad manners and a bad idea to bite, some one who is as hard as me*

> Biting one's fingernails is considered a rude and bad habit. This is also the meaning of the title. The phrase "hard as me" refers to the idiom "hard/tough as nails", which describes a strict and tough person. (credit to [Peter Taylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52815/please-dont-bite/52816?noredirect=1#comment161965_52816))

*You might loose some teeth, which will add to my arsenal to fight you.*

> Refers to the idiom "[fighting tooth and nail](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fight+tooth+and+nail)", which means competing or fighting relentlessly without holding back. (credit to [Peter Taylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52815/please-dont-bite/52816?noredirect=1#comment161965_52816))

Comment: The answer is correct, but some of the explanations seem to fall short. Another nail in the coffin (closer to demise). Nails on a board is fingernails on a blackboard. Hard as nails is an idiom for a tough guy. Fighting tooth and nail is another idiom.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wish I could give you a +1 or 2 right now. You just found all the missing hints. Good job!

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor for those interpretations. I updated the answer and credited you for the parts you mentioned.